# Recover Apple Music Playlist Deleted by Mistake

Tags: macos, music, playlist

Does anybody know how to restore an Apple Music playlist that was deleted from my Mac? It's a personal collection I've been curating for a long time and my toddler deleted it. Is there a cached version somewhere in the back end I could trace it back to?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely on your backup?

Comment: I can only guess that the Playlists are stored inside the .itl somewhere. I can confirm Time Machine stores .itl history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this helps you at all. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251373506?answerId=252694873022#252694873022

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  This is the closest answer I could find.